# Clearing the alpha channel of an NSImage

Tags: cocoa, transparency, alphablending, nsimage

It can be done by mallocing a temporary bitmap with 32bits per pixel
and then clearing the alpha component with a for loop and 
and finally turn it back into a NSImage again.

I suspect is can be done in a simpler way using a clever
combination of NSColor and [NSCompositingOperation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/GraphicsContexts/GraphicsContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH203-BCIDBEEB). Or perhaps the image 
needs to be composited with itself using drawAtPoint.

My code looks like this.

```
NSImage* img = some image with RGB and Alpha;
NSRect rect  = some rect inside the image;
[img lockFocus];
[[NSColor clearColor] set];
NSRectFillUsingOperation(rect, NSCompositeXOR);
[img unlockFocus];
```

NOTE: Setting the alpha channel to 1 can be done by 
using a blackColor with NSCompositePlusLighter.

What is the secret in clearing the alpha channel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't be fast but this will work as well:

```
NSImage *newImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[srcImage size]];
[newImage lockFocus];
[[NSColor whiteColor] set];
NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(0,0,[newImage size].width, [newImage size].height));
[srcImage compositeToPoint:NSZeroPoint operation:NSCompositeCopy];
[newImage unlockFocus];
```

Comment: Leibowitzn, yes, it looks like this will work. Will have to try this out later today.

Answer (score 2):

1. Please read the AppKit release notes on the subject of image mutability. NSImage should basically be treated as immutable.
2. All of the [pixel formats supported in graphics contexts](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB) have [premultiplied alpha](http://www.gimp.org/docs/plug-in/appendix-alpha.html).  If the alpha channel is zero, the other channels have to be zero too.

Comment: ouch, Premultiplied alpha, I didn't really notice that until now. That link that explains premultiplied alpha is well written. AppKit release notes, good point.